# MVC 4 razor Data Annotations ReadOnly

Tags: c#, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

The ReadOnly attribute does not seem to be in MVC 4. The Editable(false) attribute does not work the way I would want it to.

Is there something similar that works?

If not then how can I make my own ReadOnly attribute that would work like this:

```
public class aModel
{
   [ReadOnly(true)] or just [ReadOnly]
   string aProperty {get; set;}
}
```

so I can put this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.aProperty)
```

instead of this ( which does work ):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.aProperty , new { @readonly="readonly"})
```

or this ( which does work but values are not submitted ):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.aProperty , new { disabled="disabled"})
```

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/forms/form-disabled.html

something like this maybe?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11702643/1339704

Note:

[Editable(false)] did not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom helper like this that will check the property for the presence of a `ReadOnly` attribute:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    // in .NET 4.5 you can use the new GetCustomAttribute<T>() method to check
    // for a single instance of the attribute, so this could be slightly
    // simplified to:
    // var attr = metaData.ContainerType.GetProperty(metaData.PropertyName)
    //                    .GetCustomAttribute<ReadOnly>();
    // if (attr != null)
    bool isReadOnly = metaData.ContainerType.GetProperty(metaData.PropertyName)
                              .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ReadOnly), false)
                              .Any();

    if (isReadOnly)
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @readonly = "readonly" });
    else
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression);
}
```

The attribute is simply:

```
public class ReadOnly : Attribute
{

}
```

For an example model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [ReadOnly]
    public string PropX { get; set; }
    public string PropY { get; set; }
}
```

I have verified this works with the follow razor code:

```
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.PropX)
@Html.MyTextBoxFor(m => m.PropY)
```

Which renders as:

```
<input id="PropX" name="PropX" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Propx" />
<input id="PropY" name="PropY" type="text" value="PropY" />
```

If you need `disabled` instead of `readonly` you can easily change the helper accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with any Html helper instead of creating a new Html helper?

Comment: There is no way to make it work with all the helpers in the way you are wanting.  That is why most of the helpers have the optional `htmlAttributes` argument that will let you specify things like `readonly` as needed.  My above solution is how you would have to implement it for the requirements you gave, i.e. using an attribute.  Another solution, though I don't believe it would be any cleaner than specifying `@readonly = "readonly"`, would be to create an extension to work on the outputted HTML from the helper, i.e. `@Html.TextBoxFor().Readonly()`.

Comment: Ok, I decided to just use htmlAttributes as it is way simpler... but I will accept your answer since it seems like the closest answer to my question.

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own Html Helper Method

See here:
[Creating Customer Html Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Actually - check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232041/how-to-create-an-html-helper-to-extend-textboxfor-to-add-css-style)

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
         this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
         Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, new {  @readonly="readonly" }) 
    }
```

Comment: That looks promising... I could just create one called ReadOnlyTextBoxFor or something similar.... I suppose the data annotation is overkill.

Comment: Exactly, and in my opinion doing it this way, you are doing it in the right place. I dont think a data annotation is how you would define what is essentially a presentation attribute

Comment: Data Annotations can and often do provide information for displaying a property, i.e. the `Display` and `DisplayFormat` data annotations.