# ReadOnly Attribute in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

While the toot-tip says,

[image]

I tried using it but could not make it to work. I am not sure how it works and about its functionality. 
So what purpose does this built-in attribute `ReadOnly`serve?

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume you use this property in a view with something like `EditorFor`? Then use:

```
[Editable(false)]
public string MyProperty {get;set;}
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty, new { readonly = "readonly" })
```

If you want a readonly public property of a class use:

```
public string MyProperty {get; private set;}
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. I got your point, but what I am curious about is the use of this attribute on the model properties.

Comment: I think the readonly attribute is just used as metadata for reflection, and not by the MVC EditorFor. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute.aspx Here is a solution for a working readonly attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515441/mvc-4-razor-data-annotations-readonly

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyProperty, new { @readonly = true }) this is also working

Comment: @Marthijn Thanks for the links.Actually, I am searching for the purposes that this attribute fulfills when used on model properties. Reflection, definitely can be one of the reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.EditorFor(
  model => model.id_to_fetch,
  new {
    htmlAttributes = new {
      @class = "form-control" , @readonly = "readonly"
    }
  }
)
```